# Attaching a file using MailGun on Local vs Live

Tags: python, mailgun

Pretty simply, i'm able to attach a file on local but when I deploy this code the attachment doesn't come through...

```
def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, html_body, attachment_path=None):

    if attachment_path != None:
        if ENV == "local":
            path = open(os.path.realpath(attachment_path), "rb") 
        else:
            path = open("/app/" + attachment_path, "rb") 
        files = [("attachment", path)]  

    else:
        files = None        

    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.lhvtalenttracker.com/messages",
        auth=("api", MAILGUN_KEY),
        files=files, 
        data={"from": "LHV TalentTracker <postmaster@mg.lhvtalenttracker.com>",
                "to": recipients,
                "subject": subject,
                "html": html_body})
```

Comment: Would love to know why this got a -1. Should leave a comment for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the behavior is different on local vs live but the answer is fairly simple...

```
files = [("attachment", path)]
```

should be...

```
files = [("attachment", ("file_name", path))]
```